# Indy 10 - add cookies manually

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, indy10

I can export my cookies using "EditThisCookie" for Google Chrome.

The export looks like this:

```
"domain": ".stackoverflow.com",
"expirationDate": 1698322697,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": false,
"name": "_ga",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "some",
"id": 1
```

Now, I wish to store/parse this string to an existing `TIdHTTP` Cookie Manager.

How can I add these values to the Cookie Manager using `TIdCookie`?

This is what I tried, with no luck:

```pascal
procedure ImportCookies (JSONCookies: string; CookieManager: TIdCookieManager);
var
  StringList: TStringList;
  I : Integer;
  InCookie : Boolean;
  MyCookie: TidCookie;
    
  function BoolStrToBool(s: string): Boolean;
  begin
    if Copy(UpperCase(Trim(s)), 1, 4) = 'TRUE' then Exit(True) else Exit(False);
  end;
    
begin
  InCookie         := False;
  StringList       := TStringList.Create;
  try
    StringList.Text:= JSONCookies;
    for I := 0 to StringList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if Trim(StringList.Strings[i]) = '{' then
      begin
        InCookie := True;
        MyCookie := CookieManager.CookieCollection.Add;
        Continue;
      end;
    
      if (Trim(StringList.Strings[i]) = '}') or (Trim(StringList.Strings[i]) = '},') then
      begin
        InCookie := False;
        Continue;
      end;
    
      if InCookie then
      begin
        if Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 1, 9) = '"domain":' then
        begin
          StringList.Strings[i] := Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 10, MaxInt);
          MyCookie.Domain := GetBetween(StringList.Strings[i], '"', '"');
          Continue;
        end;
        if Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 1, 11) = '"hostOnly":' then
        begin
          StringList.Strings[i] := Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 12, MaxInt);
          MyCookie.HostOnly := BoolStrToBool(StringList.Strings[i]);
          Continue;
        end;
        if Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 1, 11) = '"httpOnly":' then
        begin
          StringList.Strings[i] := Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 12, MaxInt);
          MyCookie.HttpOnly := BoolStrToBool(StringList.Strings[i]);
          Continue;
        end;
        if Copy (StringList.Strings[i], 1, 7) = '"name":' then
        begin
          StringList.Strings[i] := Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 8, MaxInt);
          MyCookie.CookieName := GetBetween(StringList.Strings[i], '"', '"');
          Continue;
        end;
        if Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 1, 7) = '"path":' then
        begin
          StringList.Strings[i] := Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 8, MaxInt);
          MyCookie.Path := GetBetween(StringList.Strings[i], '"', '"');
          Continue;
        end;
        if Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 1, 9) = '"secure":' then
        begin
          StringList.Strings[i] := Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 10, MaxInt);
          MyCookie.Secure := BoolStrToBool(StringList.Strings[i]);
          Continue;
        end;
        if Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 1, 8) = '"value":' then
        begin
          StringList.Strings[i] := Copy(StringList.Strings[i], 9, MaxInt);
          MyCookie.Path := GetBetween(StringList.Strings[i], '"', '"');
          Continue;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    StringList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I don't see why I'd need a `TIdURI` instance - the origin shouldn't matter, since there's a destination domain already?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, your code can be greatly simplified if you use an actual JSON parser, as well as existing RTL/library functions, such as:

- `StrUtils.StartsText()` or `IdGlobal.TextStartsWith()`
- `SysUtils.StrToBool()`
- `SysUtils.AnsiExtractQuotedStr()` or `IdGlobalProtocols.UnquotedStr()`
- `IdGlobal.PosInStrAray()`
- etc.

Or, you could simply reformat the exported cookie data into a standard HTTP cookie format and then let `TIdCookieManager.AddServerCookie()` do all of the parsing for you (but then you would need a `TIdURI`).

In any case, `TIdURI` is used by `TIdCookieManager`'s parser, as certain aspects of a cookie need to be validated against the origin it came from. For instance, when determining the cookie's Path, or matching it against a domain/host, or even just knowing what the origin host is for a `HostOnly` cookie, or whether an `HttpOnly` cookie was received over HTTP, etc. There are rules to cookie processing, when receiving cookies, and when sending cookies to servers, that are tied to the cookie's origin URL.

In your case, since you are skipping `TIdCookieManager.AddServerCookie()`, you don't really need a `TIdURI` since Chrome has already done the heavy processing for you.

However, one thing that `AddServerCookie()` does do, which you are not doing, is it adds the `TIdCookie` to an internal `TIdCookies` list that is later used when deciding which cookies get sent back to which servers in `TIdHTTP` requests (see `TIdCookieManager.GenerateClientCookies()`).

So, it is not enough to just call `TIdCookieManager.CookieCollection.Add()`, which merely creates the `TIdCookie` object.  You would also need to call `TIdCookieManager.CookieCollection.AddCookie()` - which also takes a `TIdURI`, though this one is optional, whereas the one in `AddServerCookie()` is required.

So, try something more like this:

```pascal
procedure ImportCookies(JSONCookies: string; CookieManager: TIdCookieManager);
var
  StringList: TStringList;
  I : Integer;
  MyCookie: TidCookie;
  S, FieldName, FieldValue: string;

  procedure AddMyCookieIfReady;
  begin
    if MyCookie <> nil then
    begin
      if not CookieManager.CookieCollection.AddCookie(MyCookie, nil) then
      begin
        MyCookie.Collection := nil;
        MyCookie.Free;
      end;
      MyCookie = nil;
    end;
  end;

begin
  StringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    StringList.Text := JSONCookies;
    MyCookie := nil;

    for I := 0 to StringList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      s := Trim(StringList.Strings[I]);

      if s = '{' then
      begin
        AddMyCookieIfReady;
        MyCookie := CookieManager.CookieCollection.Add;
        Continue;
      end;
    
      if TextStartsWith(s, '}') then
      begin
        AddMyCookieIfReady;
        Continue;
      end;
    
      if (MyCookie = nil) or (not TextStartsWith(s, '"')) then
        Continue;

      Delete(s, 1, 1);
      FieldName := Fetch(s, '"');
      Fetch(s, ':');
      FieldValue := UnquotedStr(TrimLeft(s));

      case PosInStrArray(FieldName, ['domain', 'hostOnly', 'httpOnly', 'name', 'path', 'secure', 'value'], False) of
        0: begin
          if TextStartsWith(FieldValue, '.') then Delete(FieldValue, 1, 1);
          MyCookie.Domain := FieldValue;
        end;
        1: MyCookie.HostOnly := StrToBool(FieldValue);
        2: MyCookie.HttpOnly := StrToBool(FieldValue);
        3: MyCookie.CookieName := FieldValue;
        4: MyCookie.Path := FieldValue;
        5: MyCookie.Secure := StrToBool(FieldValue);
        6: MyCookie.Value := FieldValue;
      end;
    end;

    AddMyCookieIfReady;
  finally
    StringList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up :) My code in the question was rather lazy coded, to see if I can add the cookies. Your code is of course much better :)

Comment: quick question. Sometimes domains appear with a "dot" in the beginning. afaik, this is a wildcard. Is this properly handled in Indy10? Cause some cookies don't send... Thank you :)

Comment: e.g. a cookie with the domain ".stackoverflow.com" doesn't seem to be sent to a "www.stackoverflow.com" URL...

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss it is not a wildcard (at least, not in modern specs) and yes, Indy handles leading dots. There is more to sending back a cookie than just matching the domain. If a cookie is not being sent and you think it should be, I would have to see the actual cookie and the URL being requested.

Comment: it's in the example above. `TIdCookie`'s `domain` property is filled with ".stackoverflow.com" and I make a request to `https://www.stackoverflow.com` - when I change the domain to `www.stackoverflow.com`, the cookie successfully sends. Something is still missing in my opinion.... `TidURI`? It works, when the webserver returns a cookie with the domain `.stackoverflow` - without adding manually... Do you want me to create a new question for this issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: It also works when I remove the leading dot, however I don't want to break any functionality intentionally...

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss if Indy parses a cookie, it always strips off a leading dot on a domain, per current cookie specs.

Comment: thank you for editing the answer. I thought the dot at the beginning is essential and necessary.